# Dungeon Crawler: Level 1

Tags: cipher, knowledge, video-games

<sub>You are the protagonist in a game designed by NeedAName Inc. Proceed through the levels using
your video game knowledge to solve the puzzles therein. Solve all levels and beat the game!</sub>

---

### Level 1: Whose Lines Are These Anyways?

[Next Level](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23155/dungeon-crawler-level-2-5)

You enter the first room of the game's dungeon and see a wall displaying a list of data. Each line has a sequence of numbers followed by a genre of game and you recognize that each line represents a quote from a game. Use this information to determine the quote and the game/series that the quote is from.

> **A**. `2 1 6 4!` - *Shooter/Flyer*
>   **B**. `3 2 3!` - *Adventure/RPG*
>   **C**. `8!` - *Fighter*
>   **D**. `3. 3 5 7.` - *Adventure/RPG*
>   **E**. `6 3!` - *Fighter*
>   **F**. `5 3 6` - *First-Person Shooter*
>   **G**. `4 1 5, 3 6.` - *Adventure/RPG*
>   **H**. `1 2 5.` - *Adventure/RPG*
>   **I**. `3 4 4 2 9.` - *Simulation*
>   **J**. `6 5!` - *Fighter*
>   **K**. `3 4 2 1 3!` - *Platformer/Puzzle*
>   **L**. `2'1 9 2 2 5! 4 4!` - *Adventure/RPG*
>   **M**. `3 4 4!` - *Fighter*
>   **N**. `3 4 9 10 6` - *Real-Time Strategy*
>   **O**. `3 4 4 3 6 2 2.` - *Scrolling Shooter*

The exit to the dungeon has a voice recognition device; what quotes and corresponding games/series do you read to the device?

Comment: A gentleman and a scholar @GentlePurpleRain, thanks for the cleanup!

Comment: Looks like F is a bit of a roadblock. I've never played the game/series that it's from, but it showed up on every list of game quotes that I viewed, so I took it that it is popular. If you need another hint, let me know

Comment: I'm pretty sure I got F. - can that door open so we can go to lvl 2?

Comment: @Spacemonkey, I'll add level 2 soon. Good job getting F

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**A**. `2 1 6 4!` - *Shooter/Flyer*

> Do a Barrel Roll! - *Star Fox 64*

**B**. `3 2 3!` - *Adventure/RPG*

> Fus Ro Dah! - *The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim*

**C**. `8!` - *Fighter*

> Hadouken! - *Street Fighter*

**I**. `3 4 4 2 9.` - *Simulation*

> You have died of dysentery - *Oregon Trail*

**J**. `6 5!` - *Fighter*

> Falcon Punch! - *Super Smash Bros.*

**K**. `3 4 2 1 3!` - *Platformer/Puzzle*

> The cake is a lie! - *Portal*

**N**. `3 4 9 10 6` - *Real-Time Strategy*

> You must construct additional pylons - *Starcraft*

**O**. `3 4 4 3 6 2 2.` - *Scrolling Shooter*

> All your base are belong to us - *Zero Wing* (is it bad that I needed to use google to find the name of the game?)

Answer (score 5):

**A**. `2 1 6 4!` - *Shooter/Flyer*

> Do a barrel roll! - *Star Fox 64*

**D**. `3. 3 5 7.` - *Stealth/Action*

> War. War never changes. - *Fallout 3*

**E**. `6 3!` - *Fighter*

> Finish him! - *Mortal Kombat*

**G**. `4 1 5, 3 6.` - *Adventure/RPG*

> Stay a while, and listen. - *Diablo 2*

**I**. `3 4 4 2 9.` - *Simulation*

> You have died of dysentery. - *Oregon Trail*

**L**. `2'1 9 2 2 5! 4 4!` - *Adventure/RPG*

> It's dangerous to go alone! Take this! - *Legend of Zelda*

**M**. `3 4 4!` - *Fighter*

> Get over here! - *Mortal Kombat*

Comment: While looking around at popular game quotes, I thought it was amusing compared to **D** - "Was has changed." -Metal Gear Solid 4

Comment: @DoubleDouble Something from Metal Gear was definitely my first thought when I saw stealth/action.

Comment: Hilariously, when I wrote the genre, I mixed the quote up with the one from Metal Gear Solid, that's why I put not quite the right genre

Comment: Giving the acceptance to Logician for being the first one to answer and have the most titles. But thanks for your contribution and have a +1

Answer (score 4):

**F**

> Would you kindly...          -*Bioshock*

Answer (score 3):

**H**. `1 2 5.` - *Adventure/RPG*

> I am error. - Zelda 2

**O**. `3 4 4 3 6 2 2.` - *Scrolling Shooter*

> All your base are belong to us. - Zero Wing