# Dungeon Crawler: Level 2.5

Tags: riddle, knowledge, video-games

<sub>You are the protagonist in a game designed by NeedAName Inc. Proceed through the levels using
your video game knowledge to solve the puzzles therein. Solve all levels and beat the game!</sub>

---

### Level 2.5: A Poetic Riddle

After a weird glitch in Level 2, you find yourself transported to Level 2.5 . You wonder what happened in that weird level, but find that you don't want to dwell on it; the game developers probably should've hired beta testers. Moving on, you find a riddle scrawled on the walls:

> One kills with range or mythic pet
>   No passive vet this fighter yet.
>
> Another kills by proxy host
>   A frightful host he proudly boasts.
>
> One bashes skulls with just one fist
>   A brute, for this does he exist.
>
> A shielded elemental mage
>   Dare not enrage this spellwise sage.
>
> A righteous man, this holy knight
>   He conquers night with hallowed light.
>
> To shadows this one is confined
>   Both flesh and mind be struck in kind.
>
> The last a man of varied shapes
>   The beasts he tames, their forms he drapes.

Based off the riddle, you recognize the game and enter it's name into the keypad at the door. What game is it?

[Previous Level](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23025/dungeon-crawler-level-1)  [Next Level](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23157/dungeon-crawler-level-3)

Comment: It sounds like it could be a variety of games that follow the typical class pattern.

Comment: @EngineerToast I wanted it to be vague enough that it wasn't immediately obvious which it was (though clearly I failed) but the details provided as well as specific wording at various points helps narrow down exactly which game it is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Sounds like Diablo 2

One kills with range or mythic pet
 No passive vet this fighter yet.

> Amazon

Another kills by proxy host
 A frightful host he proudly boasts.

> Necromancer - has undead minions

One bashes skulls with just one fist
 A brute, for this does he exist.

> Barbarian smash

A shielded elemental mage
 Dare not enrage this spellwise sage.

> Sorcerer

A righteous man, this holy knight
 He conquers night with hallowed light.

> Paladin

To shadows this one is confined
 Both flesh and mind be struck in kind.

> Assassin

The last a man of varied shapes
 The beasts he tames, their forms he drapes.

> Druid

Comment: Alright, too easy then. Level 3 coming soon

Comment: Another hint is probably the level 2.5. The perspective in which the game is called [2.5D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2.5D)

Comment: Should be Sorcer*ess*, though.