# Dungeon Crawler: Level 3

Tags: cipher, knowledge, video-games

<sub>You are the protagonist in a game designed by NeedAName Inc. Proceed through the levels using
your video game knowledge to solve the puzzles therein. Solve all levels and beat the game!</sub>

---

### Level 3: Cheat Codes

You enter the third room of the dungeon, and find a paper with what you recognize as hex cheat codes.
The door to the exit of the room has a gameshark and a keypad awaiting a cheat code entry.
The list of codes reads:

> 41207472
>   75652067
>   616d6572
>   206b6e6f
>   77732074
>   68652063
>   6f646520
>   746f2064
>   65636970
>   6865723a
>   42594150
>   50575a4c
>   53424144
>   46435251

Using the information hidden in the cheat codes, what is the cheat code that you enter to move on to the next level?

[Previous Level](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23155/dungeon-crawler-level-2-5)

Comment: thereisnocowlevel!!!!!!!   sry... my SC days hijacked my hands for a second

Comment: Any hints to the second key? I only got as far as hexmefourbijlzof

Comment: @Spacemonkey I almost named this one SCL, but decided to save it for a future level. You're very close (obviously) Dark Truth, there must be a subtle difference in the way we wrote the key. In my version, the last two 'parts' are written the same (hope that's helpful without being too spoily or revealing)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say

> EE6B2800

Converting the hexcode to ascii gives:

> A true gamer knows the code to decipher:BYAPPWZLSBADFCRQ

The code to decipher(Vigenere) the last part is the Konami Code (with two start buttons at the end. Only got this one after the tip in the comments. I only remember it with a single start button at the end while wikipedia doesn't say anything about a start button at all.):

> BYAPPWZLSBADFCRQ : code[uuddlrlrbass] = hexmefourbillion

Converting to hexadecimal:

> 4,000,000,000 = EE6B2800 (base16)

I tried to do something with that last bit but putting it into an ascii converter again only leads to garbage.

Comment: That is the correct answer. The hint that it was the final step was that it, like other gameshark cheat codes provided, is a one byte hexcode. Great job getting to the bottom of it!

Answer (score 2):

Partial answer:

> Converting the Hex codes to a string gives:
>  A true gamer knows the code to decipher: **BYAPPWZLSBADFCRQ**
> *(I assumed the non-hex line returns weren't part of it, anyway it can't be converted since they weren't in hex to start off with)*
>
> My guess would be that a famous cheat code is necessary to decipher that (like the konami code, but that gives nonsense. So probably another one like it)

Comment: Line returns were indeed irrelevant, just a a way to separate the hex into 1 byte cheats. As for the 'famous cheat code' you speak of, what did you try for the one you suggested?

Comment: I tried the same as Dark Truth. I don't get the step where the konami code gives him hexmefourbillion. When I thought of the code I was thinking directions on the keyboard (i.e. up from B is H)

Comment: Spoilers Ahead: This was caused by my using the code that I used with my brother in Contra. This is apparently a variation of the 'normal' version which does not include Select or Start at the end. So the version I had was UUDDLRLRBASS, as opposed to UUDDLRLRBA or sometimes with a single S at the end I think in other games