# Dungeon Crawler - Final Level

Tags: riddle, mathematics, cipher, physics, video-games

<sub>You are the protagonist in a game designed by NeedAName Inc. Proceed through the levels using
your video game knowledge to solve the puzzles therein. Solve all levels and beat the game!</sub>

---

## Level 4: Secret Cow Boss Level

[Previous Level](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23157/dungeon-crawler-level-3)

Having bested the previous levels and proven your prowess with games, you now find yourself in the inner workings of a
console running a video game. You look around and on each of 3 walls you see a section with information written. On
the floor of the room in the center, you see: 'Part 1 → Part 2 → Part 3 → Who are you?'. Using the information on the walls and your
knowledge (video game and otherwise), can you answer the final question and beat the game?

### Part 1: Physics

$8.9875517873681764 \times 10^{16}$
$3.6266180501548694449 \times 10^{47}$
$7.3890561073081489$
$9.3094189052089 \times 10^{9}$
$1.64461934145166806681$
$8.396989835536 \times 10^{-6}$
$3.6266180501548694449 \times 10^{47}$
$7.3890561073081489$

### Part 2: Memory

- **0x00000000: 0**
- **0x00000001-00000005: 19--**

  - 0x00000001 htrit ipvgw ifsfj iccsk titwr weyfp cqgc. jqobe xjcsz giovg lqxwj elkew xudvc rpvko sxit.
  - 0x00000002 vside bcmpx csanp rqexm ezpet zjwem peup. ttrup hvzgt ntzpg ,tjqy vaake ljatp .
  - 0x00000003 wyzji mphce atrmo jctv, yoglg gsiwa oolkx .mxhp hifes raojx jpwjc spxqq rnm.
  - 0x00000004 yzvqd glqqf wlanp izas, nlmmp qhctu sxmpo .amau twvsi debcs heljf jcwvz jrylt rf?
  - 0x00000005 cyesa mzkez rxomp ,mody weuze ofwj. fjyhq fxbhf ymylw hrflx goswl pdi.
- **0x00000006-00000007: #--**

  - 0x00000006 sfmye usiux eqldc iceyw e,xtx jzrqy pyioz zj.wj elkyw yaoea kelir bhen, ppzsj gikav tvf.
  - 0x00000007 jfqfn pthhp qflfj swoss txlrv esrit d.cqf vjuoo itxcx pfwpk qctuh tzgxi fkjdw .
- **0x00000008-00000009: --**

  - 0x00000008 jphle izk,u zpiif c,tnf qgeso sotrf tjzr. kewdo vcjky eqfjy enoix tjyev tss.
  - 0x00000009 htvxt pqjqf vxtbe mqyw, nrflh hcsra etwe. ssbmb ycdtx xcbyc qfjnn etroj vnsd?

### Part 3: Graphics

$\begin{bmatrix}
9&9&9&9&9&9&9&4&4&4&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
9&9&9&9&9&9&3&9&9&9&8&4&9&9&9&9\\
9&9&9&9&9&3&4&4&4&4&4&4&8&9&9&9\\
9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9\\
9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&4&4&4\\
9&4&9&4&9&4&9&4&9&9&9&9&7&9&9&9\\
7&6&7&6&7&6&7&6&7&9&9&9&7&9&9&9\\
9&2&9&2&9&2&9&2&9&9&9&9&7&9&9&9\\
9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&9&7&9&9&9\\
4&4&4&4&4&4&4&4&4&4&4&4&7&4&4&4
\end{bmatrix}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
9&4&4&4&4&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
7&9&9&9&9&7&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
7&9&9&9&9&7&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\
7&9&9&9&9&7&9&9&9&9&3&1&5&8&0&0\\
7&9&9&9&9&7&9&9&9&9&9&7&7&0&0&0\\
7&9&9&9&9&7&9&9&9&4&4&7&7&4&4&0\\
7&9&9&9&9&7&9&9&7&4&4&4&4&4&4&7\\
7&9&9&9&9&7&9&9&9&7&9&9&9&9&7&0\\
7&4&4&4&4&7&4&4&4&7&4&4&4&4&7&0
\end{bmatrix}$

The accepted answer will address all parts of the puzzle and provide an answer to each. Teamwork is encouraged, if you want to make a community wiki, feel free.

Comment: Unless my dictionary lies, the only English word that is a cryptogram of "ssbmb" is "llama". Does anybody know any famous video game llama characters?

Comment: Well there's Llamatron...

Comment: @Kevin mine shows the same thing. Good thing I came prepared for the cryptanalysis this time!

Comment: Is NeedAName Inc. abbreviated [NaN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN) by any chance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I went ahead and jumped to part 3 with the information we had.

> I mapped the numbers in the 2D arrays in part 3 to the answers that were found for part 2 and interpreted it as ASCII. This is the result: http://pastebin.com/SNjBKUU0 (sorry I couldn't figure out how to format it here). I figured out #8 and #5 by figuring out what the image should show and doing some Googling.

5:

> 1947, year of the [first video game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cathode_Ray_Tube_Amusement_Device) made entirely with analog electronic devices.

8:

> Event 41 in Super Smash Bros takes place on Final Destination with Mario, Sonic, and Snake.

Final answer:

> I am Mario. Given away by the Piranha Plant and the ? blocks.

Answer (score 6):

Well, I think I've got the physics part:

> The numbers appear to all be squares of physical constants, modulo a certain amount of rounding.  Specifically, we have

> c (speed of light)
>  L (Avogadro's number, also sometimes written N_A)
>  e (mathematical constant)
>  F (Faraday constant)
>  A (Appears to be something called Glaisher's constant, which I haven't come across before)
>  b (Wien displacement constant)
>  L (Avogadro's number, also sometimes written N_A)
>  e (mathematical constant)

For a possible answer to part 1 of

> cLeFAbLE

Edit:  Based on dperry's decryption of the riddles in part 2, 6 and 7 appear to be

> Abra and Jynx, two more Pokémon.

Riddle 9 refers to

> the PlayStation, which ran on an MIPS microprocessor.  MIPS is a Reduced Instruction Set Computing (RISC) chip, and uses 32 bits.  (I'm sure I'm using some of the technical language wrong, but the answer is 32)

Comment: Welcome the Puzzling site @Rauwyn!! And awesome job on Part 1. Correct on all accounts, now to press forward into part 2 with that information (I will give you the slight hint that capitalization is not significant here)

Comment: Whoa, nice! I never would've noticed that. (Also, welcome! :D )

Comment: part two wants their numbers, using the first game they are #63 and #124

Answer (score 3):

Building off Rauwyn's answer (his final answer was the key to a Vigenère cypher), I worked out the questions in the Memory part and have a few answers to far:

**0x00000001-00000005: 19--**

> **0x00000001** find the release year of this platformer. float through dreams with its sucky performer *(Kirby's Dreamland, 1992)*
>  **0x00000002** the year in my name not the year of release. ported to console, i fly up with ease
>  **0x00000003** unveiled at world fair, to face her and him. i showed to many the secret of nim *(the nimatron from the 1940 New York World's Fair?)*
>  **0x00000004** world famous game expo, ill blow your mind. what is the year of the first of my kind? *(E3, 1995)*
>  **0x00000005** an analog console, im sure to amuse. find out when i was created or lose

**0x00000006-00000007: #--**

> **0x00000006** quite the small creature, with only one move. with instant withdrawal, elusive i prove.
>  **0x00000007** humanoid female you dont want to miss. youre under my spell if you give me a kiss

**0x00000008-00000009: --**

> **0x00000008** hedgehog, soldier, plumber domination. its your final final destination. *(Super Smash Bros (Brawl?))*
>  **0x00000009** first of four stations, i read from a disc. how many bits can you find in my risc?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how you got to that answer for the uninitiated among us?

Comment: added a bit of clarification, the questions in the Memory part were encoded with a Vigenère cypher, and Rauwyn's answer was the key to it

Comment: Aparrently I lost this formatting in the copy paste, but the word amuse in riddle #5 should be italicized. Also, any particular reason you numbered all of the riddles as 1?

Comment: bah, copy/paste error

Comment: 6 & 7 seem to be Pokémon: Abra and Jynx

Comment: I agree on #8 it has sonic,solid snake, mario as those roles

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment, but here's what I got.

2:

> Battlefield 1942 was ported to console and one could say it has been "flying" up in popularity since then.
>  or it could be the game "1942" released for arcade in 1984 and ported to the Famicom console in 1985. It's a scrolling flying shooter.

5:

> Might refer to the Magnavox Odyssey created in 1972 which was a digital console but widely mistaken to be an analog console.

Oops just saw Rauwyn's answer for 9.

9:

> Playstation 1 risc R3000 I believe had 32bits.

Comment: I think the the flying up does refer to a shmup and your second guess was quite popular, there were three sequels to it as well. Here is a list to a lot of arcade shmups if that is wrong http://www.shmups.com/xenocidefiles/arcade.html

Comment: 5: in this wikipedia aticle it says a lot people mislable that as analog https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_video_game_consoles_(first_generation)